# The copper's already solved this one for you. Just fill in the blank

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

The Oxford Coppa gives you the facts:

"We've arrested Jimmy, whom we saw with an axe."

"We've arrested Bobby, whose morals appall."

"One crime, two crimes, we've got evidence for them all."

You ask the copper how he uncovered all the action

The copper ejaculates: "Deduction, abduction, and ________"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it:

> Induction?

Based on the hint:

> Oxford Coppa = Oxford Comma. And thus we have to see the words after the comma...  
>  **Deduction:**
>  whom we saw with an axe
>  **Abduction:**
>  whose morals appall
>  **Induction:**
>  we've got evidence for them all